# clearing unwanted characters with replace

Tags: sql

I tried to do like this but couldn't manage to work, looking for help

```
declare @badStrings table (item varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @badStrings(item)
SELECT '>' UNION ALL
SELECT '<' UNION ALL
SELECT '(' UNION ALL
SELECT ')' UNION ALL
SELECT '!' UNION ALL
SELECT '?' UNION ALL
SELECT '@'

SELECT Replace(u.DisplayName, b.item, '') , * FROM User u, @badStrings b
```

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Are you missing the variable to store the replaced string? `select @clrstr = Replace(u.DisplayName, b.item, '') , * FROM User u, @badStrings b
select @clrstr`

Comment: thanks FutbolFan I could manage to change the code that you gave in link